# How to add two named checkboxes to one cell

Tags: vba, excel

I've looked around but can't figure out how to add two checkboxes to a single cell. Do I need to use OLEObjects.Add or not? I need to add two columns of checkboxes in column E. Thanks in advance.

Here is my attempt:

```
LRow = ActiveSheet.Range("G" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row

For cell = 2 To LRow

    If Cells(cell, "G").Value <> "" Then

        CLeft = Cells(cell, "E").Left

        CTop = Cells(cell, "E").Top

        CHeight = Cells(cell, "E").Height / 2

        CWidth = Cells(cell, "E").Width


        ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes.Add(CLeft, CTop, CWidth, CHeight).Select

        With Selection
            .Caption = ""
            .name = "cbSet1_" & cell
            .Value = xlOff
            .LinkedCell = "E" & cell
            .Display3DShading = False

        End With
    End If
Next cell

For cellF = 2 To LRow

    If Cells(cellF, "G").Value <> "" Then

        CLeftF = Cells(cellF, "E").Left

        CTopF = Cells(cellF, "E").Top

        CHeightF = Cells(cellF, "E").Height

        CWidthF = Cells(cellF, "E").Width


        ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes.Add(CLeftF, CTopF, CWidthF, CHeightF).Select

        With Selection
            .Caption = ""
            .name = "cbSet2_" & cell
            .Value = xlOff
            .Display3DShading = False
        End With
    End If
Next cellF
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a small changes to your code. We don't need two loop.

If it is not OK, let me known. Try With this.

```
LRow = ActiveSheet.Range("G" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).row

For cell = 2 To LRow

    If Cells(cell, "G").Value <> "" Then

        'Getting left, top, height and width
        CLeft = Cells(cell, "E").Left

        CTop = Cells(cell, "E").Top

        CHeight = Cells(cell, "E").Height / 2

        CWidth = Cells(cell, "E").Width / 2

        'Add first check box
        ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes.Add(CLeft, CTop, CWidth, CHeight).Select

        With Selection
            .Caption = ""
            .Name = "cbSet1_" & cell
            .Value = xlOff
            .LinkedCell = "E" & cell
            .Display3DShading = False

        End With

        'Add second check box
        ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes.Add(CLeft + CWidth, CTop, CWidth, CHeight).Select

        With Selection
            .Caption = ""
            .Name = "cbSet2_" & cell
            .Value = xlOff
            .Display3DShading = False
        End With

    End If

Next cell
```

Comment: Yes, thank you.  I see the checkboxes.  I would like to varify the names of the checkboxes. How do I do that?  Also, what difference would it make if I use OLEObjects.Add?

Comment: How do you want to verify the name? You can see it in the sheet by clicking check box, it will shown it's name at the left top corner box. The main different is code style that I think.